# jQuery dataTables : Sorting "Sticky"

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have datatables setup and it has been working great. I have the alphabetical sorting in place on a column which works just fine, however, I would like to be able to have a certain word show on the initial table load.

For example "User xxxxx" always shows first on load... "User" being the key word to find and show first. After the person clicks the column header to sort, that would no longer be default as the alphabetical sorting happens...

I see the area to add plugins: http://datatables.net/development/sorting#data_source However, I am at a loss... I was looking at the example:

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.afnSortData['dom-text'] = function  ( oSettings, iColumn )
{
    var aData = [];
    $( 'td:eq('+iColumn+') input', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings) ).each( function () {
        aData.push( this.value );
    } );
    return aData;
}
```

This makes sense on the inputs being changed. What about on initial load?